# iphone sqlite data on uitableview on iOS4

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, uitableview, master-detail, populate

I need to make a viewcontroller like the address book for example, where I show the data from a sqlite database on a grid, and after I can edit (show a new viewcontroller with the detail of the row where I can change the values), delete and insert new rows...

how can I do this or better, is there a sample to make this simply?
thanks

Comment: Really need more info. If at all useful, look into the core data libraries for data access and use the usual protocols (UITableViewDatasource, UITableViewDelegate) to do what you need to do. It's a bit of work, but not rocket science.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be helpful to get started:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/

You may want to start off with just an array/dictionary/class containing your data, then move onto trying to load it with core data as an sqlite.